# Protecting process from being accessed by other process

Tags: windows, debugging

In Windows (XP or later, x86-64, if that matters), what are the usual ways to protect your process/program from being accessed by other process even if the latter has system-level privilege?

Comment: Keep in mind that any such mucking about risks raising the ire of the user's anti-virus software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-anti-debug-reference)  paper from Symantec.com classifies and presents several anti-debugging techniques used on Windows NT-based operating systems. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29469/Introduction-Into-Windows-Anti-Debugging) from codeproject.com

---

The Windows Vista operating system introduces a new type of process, called a [protected process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463417.aspx). Historically, a privileged service (running as administrator or local system) has been able to obtain all access to a process or thread, regardless of its [DACL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), by using `SeDebugPrivilege`. 
Starting with Windows Vista, the privileges: Process Access Rights: DELETE, READ_CONTROL, WRITE_DAC, WRITE_OWNER, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS, PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD, PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, PROCESS_SET_QUOTA, PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION, PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, PROCESS_VM_READ, PROCESS_VM_WRITE
Thread Access Rights:
THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, THREAD_DIRECT_IMPERSONATION, THREAD_GET_CONTEXT, THREAD_IMPERSONATE, THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, THREAD_SET_CONTEXT, THREAD_SET_INFORMATION, THREAD_SET_THREAD_TOKEN, THREAD_TERMINATE
cannot be obtained for a protected process or thread. 
Search [more](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=protected+process+site%3amicrosoft.com) about protected process.